# Div blinking while resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrap based website and I have the following case : 
A main container and a floating left navigation menu.
The floating left navigation menu, is set to position fixed, because it is following the user scroll.

[image: problem description with the image]
What I would like is when the end user resize the window, and when the main content meets the left menu (overlap), the left menu becomes hidden, and when there is enough space the left menu comes back.

Actually, it is not really working, it is blinking. I have written a little bit of jquery binded to the resize function.
Here is the jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/cuw46rsv/5/

```
function getDiffLeftMenu(div1, div2) {
    var value = ($(div1).offset().left - $(div2).offset().left);
    console.log(value  - $(div2).width());
    if(value - $(div2).width() < 0){
        return true;
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', function(event) {

    var value = ($('.central-content').offset().left - $('#sectionsMenu').offset().left);
    if(getDiffLeftMenu('.central-content','#sectionsMenu')){
        $('#sectionsMenu').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#sectionsMenu').show();

    }
}).resize();
```

Is this possible to not have this blinking effet ?
Thanks a lot for any help.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution with your logic, .hide() method causes it to have offset 0 and that's why it's blinking (it can get stuck as hidden all the time).

https://jsfiddle.net/cuw46rsv/7/

```
function getDiffLeftMenu(div1, div2) {
    var value = ($(div1).offset().left - $(div2).offset().left);
    console.log(value  - $(div2).width());
    if(value - $(div2).width() < 0){
        return true;
    }
}
```

By using opacity offset will stay there.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {

        var value = ($('.central-content').offset().left - $('#sectionsMenu').offset().left);
        if(getDiffLeftMenu('.central-content','#sectionsMenu')){
            $('#sectionsMenu').css('opacity', 0);
        }
        else {
            $('#sectionsMenu').css('opacity', 1);

        }
    }).resize();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine ! Got the point regarding the hide(). It's logic finally! Regards.

Answer (score -1):

well you are doing it wrong, but you can solve it like this (as a workaround):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {

    var value = ($('.central-content').offset().left - $('#sectionsMenu').offset().left);
    if(getDiffLeftMenu('.central-content','#sectionsMenu')){
        setTimeout(function(){$('#sectionsMenu').hide();},20);
    }
    else {
        $('#sectionsMenu').show();

    }
}).resize();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cuw46rsv/6/

Comment: This also doesn't guarantee the solution, it's still can stuck being hidden entire time...